# Divide free space between flex and gap

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I want to display a lot of buttons in an element with variable width.
The buttons should always be arranged in such a way that it looks as nice as possible.

The best possibility I have found so far is:

```css
.container {  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.75rem;
}

button {
  flex: 0.4; 
}
```

This works well if the container is wide, but badly if not.

Is there a possibility to distribute the free space per line not only inside the button (flex:.4) but also between the buttons ?

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");

document.querySelector(".switch").addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.toggle("mobile");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80rem;
  max-height: 60rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.75rem;
}

.mobile {
  width: 20rem;
}

button {
  flex: 0.4;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button>span {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

button>p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.switch {
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="switch">
  toggle width
</button>

<div class="container">
  <button><span>&#129446;</span>
    <p>Dragon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129447;</span>
    <p>Orangutan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129448;</span>
    <p>Skunk</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129449;</span>
    <p>Flamingo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129451;</span>
    <p>Beaver</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129452;</span>
    <p>Buffalo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#x1F981;</span>
    <p>Lion</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129421;</span>
    <p>Gorilla</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129414;</span>
    <p>Duck</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129417;</span>
    <p>Owl</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129449;</span>
    <p>Flamingo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129451;</span>
    <p>Beaver</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129452;</span>
    <p>Buffalo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129426;</span>
    <p>Giraffe</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129427;</span>
    <p>Zebra</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129429;</span>
    <p>Brachiosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129439;</span>
    <p>Mosquito</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129439;</span>
    <p>Mosquito</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129441;</span>
    <p>Badger</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129442;</span>
    <p>Swan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129443;</span>
    <p>Mammut</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129445;</span>
    <p>Sloth</p>
  </button>

  <button><span>&#129441;</span>
    <p>Badger</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129442;</span>
    <p>Swan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129443;</span>
    <p>Mammut</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129445;</span>
    <p>Sloth</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129446;</span>
    <p>Dragon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129430;</span>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129419;</span>
    <p>Butterfly</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129420;</span>
    <p>Rendeer</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129424;</span>
    <p>Crab</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#x1F981;</span>
    <p>Lion</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129421;</span>
    <p>Gorilla</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129414;</span>
    <p>Duck</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129417;</span>
    <p>Owl</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129428;</span>
    <p>Hedgehog</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129430;</span>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129419;</span>
    <p>Butterfly</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129420;</span>
    <p>Rendeer</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129424;</span>
    <p>Crab</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129426;</span>
    <p>Giraffe</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129427;</span>
    <p>Zebra</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129429;</span>
    <p>Brachiosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129446;</span>
    <p>Dragon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129447;</span>
    <p>Orangutan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129448;</span>
    <p>Skunk</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129449;</span>
    <p>Flamingo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129451;</span>
    <p>Beaver</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129452;</span>
    <p>Buffalo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#x1F981;</span>
    <p>Lion</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129421;</span>
    <p>Gorilla</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129414;</span>
    <p>Duck</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129417;</span>
    <p>Owl</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129449;</span>
    <p>Flamingo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129451;</span>
    <p>Beaver</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129452;</span>
    <p>Buffalo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129426;</span>
    <p>Giraffe</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129427;</span>
    <p>Zebra</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129429;</span>
    <p>Brachiosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129439;</span>
    <p>Mosquito</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129439;</span>
    <p>Mosquito</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129441;</span>
    <p>Badger</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129442;</span>
    <p>Swan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129443;</span>
    <p>Mammut</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129445;</span>
    <p>Sloth</p>
  </button>

  <button><span>&#129441;</span>
    <p>Badger</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129442;</span>
    <p>Swan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129443;</span>
    <p>Mammut</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129445;</span>
    <p>Sloth</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129446;</span>
    <p>Dragon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129430;</span>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129419;</span>
    <p>Butterfly</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129420;</span>
    <p>Rendeer</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129424;</span>
    <p>Crab</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#x1F981;</span>
    <p>Lion</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129421;</span>
    <p>Gorilla</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129414;</span>
    <p>Duck</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129417;</span>
    <p>Owl</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129428;</span>
    <p>Hedgehog</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129430;</span>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129419;</span>
    <p>Butterfly</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129420;</span>
    <p>Rendeer</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129424;</span>
    <p>Crab</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129426;</span>
    <p>Giraffe</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129427;</span>
    <p>Zebra</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129429;</span>
    <p>Brachiosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129446;</span>
    <p>Dragon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129447;</span>
    <p>Orangutan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129448;</span>
    <p>Skunk</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129449;</span>
    <p>Flamingo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129451;</span>
    <p>Beaver</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129452;</span>
    <p>Buffalo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#x1F981;</span>
    <p>Lion</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129421;</span>
    <p>Gorilla</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129414;</span>
    <p>Duck</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129417;</span>
    <p>Owl</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129449;</span>
    <p>Flamingo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129451;</span>
    <p>Beaver</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129452;</span>
    <p>Buffalo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129426;</span>
    <p>Giraffe</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129427;</span>
    <p>Zebra</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129429;</span>
    <p>Brachiosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129439;</span>
    <p>Mosquito</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129439;</span>
    <p>Mosquito</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129441;</span>
    <p>Badger</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129442;</span>
    <p>Swan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129443;</span>
    <p>Mammut</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129445;</span>
    <p>Sloth</p>
  </button>

  <button><span>&#129441;</span>
    <p>Badger</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129442;</span>
    <p>Swan</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129443;</span>
    <p>Mammut</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129445;</span>
    <p>Sloth</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129446;</span>
    <p>Dragon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129437;</span>
    <p>Raccoon</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129438;</span>
    <p>Lobster</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129430;</span>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129419;</span>
    <p>Butterfly</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129420;</span>
    <p>Rendeer</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129424;</span>
    <p>Crab</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#x1F981;</span>
    <p>Lion</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129421;</span>
    <p>Gorilla</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129414;</span>
    <p>Duck</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129417;</span>
    <p>Owl</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129423;</span>
    <p>Rhinoceros</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129428;</span>
    <p>Hedgehog</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129430;</span>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129419;</span>
    <p>Butterfly</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129420;</span>
    <p>Rendeer</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129424;</span>
    <p>Crab</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129425;</span>
    <p>Octopus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129426;</span>
    <p>Giraffe</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129427;</span>
    <p>Zebra</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129429;</span>
    <p>Brachiosaurus</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129431;</span>
    <p>Locust</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129432;</span>
    <p>Kangaroo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129433;</span>
    <p>Alpaca</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129434;</span>
    <p>Peacock</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129435;</span>
    <p>Hippo</p>
  </button>
  <button><span>&#129436;</span>
    <p>Bird</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

or: https://codepen.io/koljal/pen/RwYBpjy

Comment: Is there a reason for fixing the width in rems? Would it serve your purpose to set it in vw unts so it is more responsive?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<p>` element cannot be the child of a `<button>`. This needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Right, no p in button, fixed now in the codepen.

Comment: @AHaworth thank you for the hint, the solution is: `flex: calc(100vw / 300);` It works fine for all widths, see the codepen :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make the flex property responsive:
`flex: 1vw;`